How should I go about replacing this hole in my vinyl siding without extra siding on hand?
I have an 8” x 9” hole in my vinyl siding where our electric meter used to be before it moved. There is also a large piece of conduit over the hole. I am trying to cover this hole
I have tried getting a blank mounting box and putting that over the hole but the gap between the siding and the metal conduit is only about 1 and 1/4” thick as opposed to the much thicker mounting box.
Also tried using some of the mismatched leftover siding in my garage left by the previous owner but it is not the right size.
Are there any other solutions I could try? I have thought about going out and finding my exact siding, but have read that can be a pain, but I will do it if it’s my only option.


No chance there's a manufacturer's/model name on the back of one of the existing pieces of siding that you can use to source a replacement?

It's not really that hard to remove a section of siding with a $7 siding tool.

Welcome. Please take the [tour]. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

You have here a fairly common "Dutch lap" profile. It's probably a 4" or 5" board. I would check local stores for something close, then fit an overlay, which may involve two connected panels.
Use pop rivets or short round-head sheet metal screws and urethane caulk along the edges to secure it. It'll blend in much better than most other patch solutions.

If you're not fussy, weatherproof bitumin-aluminum tape like Flashtac
optionally put some wooden sticks in there so the tape follows the shape of the vinyl.
If you're a little fussy, aluminum flashing sheeting formed to match the vinyl profile against an unobstructed section of the wall and then held in place over the hole with urethane sealant and banana peel rivets.  (or alternatively form it into a box shape to fill the hole)
